# SQL Query with multiple use of parameters

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to know how to rewrite this query, so that I pass the date parameters only once -

```
Select a.recorded_hours,
and (((a.employee_hours+b.Quantity)/( ('&To_date' - '&from_date')*24))
From table1 a, table2 b
Where a.code=b.code
and a.site = b.site
and a.reg_date between '&from_date' and '&to_date'
```

Comment: search for oracle and placeholders (or bind variables).

Comment: What is the `and` keyword in front of the second column expression? `and (((a.emplo`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2):

You can receive the parameters into a single row from DUAL in CTE (`WITH  ... as`) and join that table to your query:

```
with Parms as (
   select  '&from_date' as FROM_DATE, '&To_date' as TO_DATE from DUAL
   )
Select a.recorded_hours,
       ((  (a.employee_hours+b.Quantity) / ((P.TO_DATE - P.FROM_DATE)*24)))
From table1 a
     
     inner join
     table2 b
     on a.code=b.code
     and a.site = b.site

     inner join
     Parms P
     on a.reg_date between P.FROM_DATE and P.TO_DATE
```

I also changed the join syntax for tables a and b to the more modern `INNER JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Just put the & character twice:

```sql
--  This will ask you to enter parameter twice:
Select SubStr('ABCDEFGHI', &Pos, 1) || SubStr('123456789', &Pos, 1) "CELL" From Dual;

--  ... and this just once
Select SubStr('ABCDEFGHI', &&Pos, 1) || SubStr('123456789', &&Pos, 1) "CELL" From Dual;
```

Result is the same:

```sql
/*
CELL
----
C3      */
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **two** ampersands instead:

```
SELECT a.recorded_hours,
       ((a.employee_hours + b.Quantity) / (('&&To_date' - '&&from_date') * 24))
  FROM table1 a, table2 b
 WHERE     a.code = b.code
       AND a.site = b.site
       AND a.reg_date BETWEEN '&&from_date' AND '&&to_date';
```

---

How does that work? Like this:

```
SQL> select '&&par_name' from dual where '&&par_name' = 'ABC';
Enter value for par_name: ABC

'AB
---
ABC
```

As you can see, only one prompt for substitution variable. What if you re-execute the same (last) statement? Query works, but it uses **previously** entered value:

```
SQL> /

'AB
---
ABC
```

If you want to use a new value, **undefine** variable:

```
SQL> undefine par_name
SQL> /
Enter value for par_name: XYZ

no rows selected

SQL>
```